# I am working on a spring mvc project and I want to submit values from two drop boxes and a text box

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

I  have to take month (drop box), year (drop box) and text from the user, which is packaged as a 'Permissions' class object, and sent to the server.

```
<div id="Setpermissions" class="modal">

    <div class="modal-content animate" >
        <div class="imgcontainer">
            <span onclick="document.getElementById('Setpermissions').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
        </div>

        <form id="my-form" action = "Permissions" method="post">

            <select name="mon" multiple="multiple" size="10">
                <%
                    for(i=1;i<13;i++) {
                        out.println("<option value = " + i + "> " + Month.of(i) + "<option>");
                    }
                %>

            </select>

            <select name="year" multiple="multiple" size="10">
                <%
                    int year = Integer.parseInt(Year.now().toString());
                    for(i=1;i<13;i++) {
                        out.println("<option value = " + year + "> " + year + "<option>");
                        year=year-1;
                    }
                %>

            </select>

            <fieldset>
                <label><input id="Reason" placeholder="Reason" type="text" name="Reason"></label>
            </fieldset>
            <!-- use this for server-side processing -->

            <input type="submit" name="submitted" value="submit" />

        </form>


    </div>

</div>
```

Here is my servlet code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Permissions", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String Permissions(@Validated Permissions per, Model model) {

    System.out.println(per.getReason());
    return "user";
}

}
```

Permissions class:

```
public class Permissions {
    private int mon;
    private int year;
    private String reason;
    private String permission;

    public String getPermission() {
        return permission;
    }

    public String getReason() {
        return reason;
    }
}
```

But I am not getting directed to  the right page (user.jsp), and the values are not reaching the servlet. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Things you should try:

1. Your backing object (Permissions in this case) should have both Getters and Setters for all fields. This is because, when you click submit and send your request to your backend, Spring will call the setX(x) methods for each field. (ex. setYear(year)). As you have no Setters, I don't believe this will work.
2. You are using capitalized names in your HTML (Reason) instead of the exact field name (reason). I'm not sure if this affects anything, but might try it.